# Is this on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Who symbolizes Christ in J. R. R. Tolkien's "The Lord of the Rings"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18257/who-symbolizes-christ-in-j-r-r-tolkiens-the-lord-of-the-rings)

This is certainly not about Christian doctrines. The works are certainly not theological, though may have religious and even Christian overtones

It is also not about Christian culture, which has recently been squashed by the community as being off topic, which I am still upset about. It is akin to Christian *sub*-culture. Is is only meaningful to a group of people that share nothing in common except an affinity for Tolkien and his writings, who was neither a theologian nor a Church leader.

That being said, the page will definitely draw traffic to the site. But will it draw productive users to participate? I don't think this particular one will (though I still think the questions about christian gun-culture and christian patriotism would have).

So what kind of question is this and is it on-topic?